# Remove Top/Bottom Shadowing from UIWebView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview

Is there a way to remove the shadow that appears above or below a UIScrollView once you've scrolled all the way past the top or bottom?

Comment: For clarification, it's actually a UIWebView.